# NetworkOnMainThread Exception, android application

Tags: android, openstreetmap, osmdroid

I am using osmdroid bonuspack in  my android application, when I run the code I get this error NetworkOnMainThread Exception.

this is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private MapView myOpenMapView;
    private MapController mapController;

        /** Called when the activity is first created. */
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);  

            RoadManager roadManager = new OSRMRoadManager();

            myOpenMapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.openmapview);
            myOpenMapView.setTileSource(TileSourceFactory.MAPNIK);
            GeoPoint startPoint = new GeoPoint(48.13, -1.63);
           MapController mapController = myOpenMapView.getController();
            mapController.setCenter(startPoint);
            mapController.setZoom(9);
            ArrayList<GeoPoint> waypoints = new ArrayList<GeoPoint>();
            waypoints.add(startPoint);
            waypoints.add(new GeoPoint(48.4, -1.9)); //end point
            Road road = roadManager.getRoad(waypoints);
            PathOverlay roadOverlay = RoadManager.buildRoadOverlay(road, myOpenMapView.getContext());
            myOpenMapView.getOverlays().add(roadOverlay);
            myOpenMapView.invalidate();
         //   RoadManager roadManager = new MapQuestRoadManager();
            roadManager.addRequestOption("routeType=bicycle");


            final ArrayList<ExtendedOverlayItem> roadItems = 
                      new ArrayList<ExtendedOverlayItem>();
                    ItemizedOverlayWithBubble<ExtendedOverlayItem> roadNodes = 
                      new ItemizedOverlayWithBubble<ExtendedOverlayItem>(this, roadItems, myOpenMapView);
                    myOpenMapView.getOverlays().add(roadNodes);

                     Drawable marker = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.marker);
                        for (int i=0; i<road.mNodes.size(); i++){
                                RoadNode node = road.mNodes.get(i);
                                ExtendedOverlayItem nodeMarker = new ExtendedOverlayItem("Step "+i, "", node.mLocation, this);
                                nodeMarker.setMarkerHotspot(OverlayItem.HotspotPlace.CENTER);
                                nodeMarker.setMarker(marker);
                                roadNodes.addItem(nodeMarker);

                        nodeMarker.setDescription(node.mInstructions);
                        nodeMarker.setSubDescription(road.getLengthDurationText(node.mLength, node.mDuration));
                        Drawable icon = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
                        nodeMarker.setImage(icon);

                        }

}}
```

and this is the logCat:

```
11-11 04:00:01.916: E/AndroidRuntime(1040): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-11 04:00:01.916: E/AndroidRuntime(1040): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.openstreetbonus/com.example.openstreetbonus.MainActivity}: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
11-11 04:00:01.916: E/AndroidRuntime(1040):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
11-11 04:00:01.916: E/AndroidRuntime(1040):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
11-11 04:00:01.916: E/AndroidRuntime(1040):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
11-11 04:00:01.916: E/AndroidRuntime(1040):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
11-11 04:00:01.916: E/AndroidRuntime(1040):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-11 04:00:01.916: E/AndroidRuntime(1040):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-11 04:00:01.916: E/AndroidRuntime(1040):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
11-11 04:00:01.916: E/AndroidRuntime(1040):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-11 04:00:01.916: E/AndroidRuntime(1040):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
11-11 04:00:01.916: E/AndroidRuntime(1040):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
11-11 04:00:01.916: E/AndroidRuntime(1040):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
11-11 04:00:01.916: E/AndroidRuntime(1040):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-11 04:00:01.916: E/AndroidRuntime(1040): Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
11-11 04:00:01.916: E/AndroidRuntime(1040):     at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1133)
11-11 04:00:01.916: E/AndroidRuntime(1040):     at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:385)
11-11 04:00:01.916: E/AndroidRuntime(1040):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
11-11 04:00:01.916: E/AndroidRuntime(1040):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
11-11 04:00:01.916: E/AndroidRuntime(1040):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:137)
11-11 04:00:01.916: E/AndroidRuntime(1040):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
11-11 04:00:01.916: E/AndroidRuntime(1040):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
11-11 04:00:01.916: E/AndroidRuntime(1040):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
11-11 04:00:01.916: E/AndroidRuntime(1040):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
11-11 04:00:01.916: E/AndroidRuntime(1040):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
11-11 04:00:01.916: E/AndroidRuntime(1040):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
11-11 04:00:01.916: E/AndroidRuntime(1040):     at org.osmdroid.bonuspack.utils.HttpConnection.doGet(HttpConnection.java:75)
11-11 04:00:01.916: E/AndroidRuntime(1040):     at org.osmdroid.bonuspack.routing.OSRMRoadManager.getRoad(OSRMRoadManager.java:204)
11-11 04:00:01.916: E/AndroidRuntime(1040):     at com.example.openstreetbonus.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:46)
11-11 04:00:01.916: E/AndroidRuntime(1040):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
11-11 04:00:01.916: E/AndroidRuntime(1040):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
11-11 04:00:01.916: E/AndroidRuntime(1040):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
```

I followed the tutorial at this site: https://code.google.com/p/osmbonuspack/wiki/Tutorial_1

Comment: move your network related operation to a thread or asynctask

Comment: please use background task for accessing internet on main thread. you can use 'AsyncTask' or 'runonuithread' method.

Comment: @Raghunandan I don't have any network related operation

Comment: Please take this issue up with the creators of the library you are using.

Comment: Looks like the problem is in the line
    Road road = roadManager.getRoad(waypoints);
SO you may want to try restructuring to put that into an async task.

Answer (score 2):

You should use async task for network request. This link will help you to write  [Async Tasks](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidBackgroundProcessing/article.html)

Comment: I don't have any network request in my code!!

Comment: You most definitely do in code (perhaps from a library) which your code calls into.

Answer (score 0):

Since the inception of Android Honeycomb, in order to make apps more responsive, it was disallowed to use networking tasks to be performed on the "main" thread or the "ui" thread. As you are trying to perform network operations on the "main" thread itself, Android throws an exception sweetly named `NetworkOnMainThreadException`.

To workaround this issue, you can either use:- `AsyncTask`, a worker thread (by extending `Thread` class, or use `Handler`s

You can use `AsyncTask` when you want to make UI changes after the network connection is closed or update the UI as the network connection is in progress.

`Thread`s are better if you dont have any UI updations.

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid performing long running operations on the UI thread. This includes file and network access.

**StrictMode** allows to setup policies in your application to avoid doing incorrect things. For example the following setup will crash your application if it violates some of the Android policies. StrictMode should only be used during development and not in your live application.

```
StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
    .detectAll().penaltyLog().penaltyDeath().build());
StrictMode.setVmPolicy(new StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder().detectAll()
    .penaltyLog().penaltyDeath().build());
```

Try out as below :

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);       
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
}
```